# The following code, throwing the following error ...

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, astropy

```
 sun_ra=round(sunpy.sun.apparent_rightascension(t),4)*15.0
```

File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astropy/units/quantity.py", line 963, in **float**
raise TypeError('Only dimensionless scalar quantities can be '
TypeError: Only dimensionless scalar quantities can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: It would help to see your code... in particular line 31.....

Comment: Use `sunpy.sun.apparent_rightascension(t).value` to get a floating point value: `round()` knows how to deal with that. Or if you want to be more explicit: `sunpy.sun.apparent_rightascension(t).to(units.degree).value`.

Comment: Overall, though, *don't* round. Use formatting when printing the value, but otherwise, just keep the actual, exact value and don't round it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 sun_ra=round(sunpy.sun.apparent_rightascension(t),4)*15.0
```

`round` looks like the scalar Python function.  It will raise an error if given an array or list. But on Py3 I get a different error.

The other possibility is that the `sunpy` function expects a scalar, and `t` is not.  But for that I'd expect an error further into that function.

So I think your use of `round` is an error.

Comment: Almost: `sunpy.sun.apparent_rightascension` will return an `astropy.coordinate.Angle` or similar, which is an `astropy.units.Quantity` (a float with a unit attached to it). `round` obviously doesn't know how to handle that.